# Creating user using firebase phone authentication?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, swift3, firebase-authentication

[image]

I am using phone authentication for login(phone number and password) and for sign up with  user details like name, email, photo url, address, phone number and password. By using sign up phone number field requesting OTP to verify phone number. After successful verification of phone number it takes to home page.

suggest me sign up to create user with phone number and verify using OTP request using cloud firestore

Comment: you already write all the concept, now what we suggest here?

Comment: @dahiya_boy Yeah i am having concept but i don't know to save data in firebase and request OTP verification for sign up

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For send Otp used this method . 
**Mobile number Must Be with country code Ex. +1**

```
PhoneAuthProvider.provider().verifyPhoneNumber(mobileNo, uiDelegate: nil) { (verificationID, error) in

            if let error = error {
                print(error)
                APPDEL.window?.makeToast("Your mobile number is not valid")
                complition(false)
                return
            }
            UserDefaults.standard.set(verificationID, forKey: "authVerificationID")
            complition(true)
            // Sign in using the verificationID and the code sent to the user
        }
```

And verify OTP and Successfully Sign In Used This

```
let verificationID = UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: "authVerificationID")

        let credential = PhoneAuthProvider.provider().credential(
            withVerificationID: verificationID!,
            verificationCode: verificationCode)

        Auth.auth().signIn(with: credential) { (user, error) in
            if let error = error {
                print(error.localizedDescription)
                APPDEL.window?.makeToast("OTP entered is incorrect")
                complition(false)
                return
            }
            complition(true)
        }
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, how can i insert data username, phone number, password to firebase and request OTP for verification - sign up

Comment: Not pass all data you can just pass mobile number only also refer this link https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/phone-auth

Comment: @PvDev for Auth firebase do it for you, so you don't need to wrry about it.

Comment: @Jaydip Thanks for the answer. This could help me!!

Comment: @dahiya_boy thank you!!

Comment: Thanks Men @PvDev

Comment: @PvDev Just keep in mind, for any type of auth in firebase, you just need to call that auth with parameters (like email phone number or password etc) and in completion handler firebase returns you whther this auth is correct or not. Now store rest of data (name blah blah) in firebase db. if you need email or conatct for anyother reason then you have store these values also. Hope now it makes your vision more clear.

Comment: @dahiya_boy sure. Thanks for suggestions!!

Comment: @PvDev welcome..

Comment: @dahiya_boy  How to check if user's phone number is already in Firebase database before creating a new user?

Comment: @Jaydip  How to check if user's phone number is already in Firebase database before creating a new user

Comment: @Jaydip can you check out thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247982/how-to-check-users-phone-number-is-already-in-firebase-before-creating-a-new-us

Comment: @dahiya_boy can you check out thishttps://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247982/how-to-check-users-phone-number-is-already-in-firebase-before-creating-a-new-us

Comment: @PvDev Add link in proper way , use help for more details. By the way right now I unable to open the url.

Comment: @dahiya_boy https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49247982/

Comment: how can i verify that

Comment: how can i verify that